# How can I install Jelly Bean on a Micromax Funbook P275?

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, installation, buttons, micromax-funbook

I have a [Micromax Funbook P275](http://www.flipkart.com/micromax-funbook-infinity-p275-tablet/p/itmdg5cnuksd36re) tablet with Android 4.0.4 ICS installed, and I want to install 4.2 Jelly Bean on it, using [this guide](http://www.techdiscussion.in/index.php?topic=1809.msg4264#msg4264).

Since the P275 doesn't have hardware buttons for volume up/down, how can I scroll up/down in the recovery mode without the hardware buttons? The only ones on my device are the Home and the Power button.

Comment: The keys that has been mentioned are used by ClockworkMod Recovery console to change selection. There are other version of ClockworkMod that are touch based, which does not need these volume buttons. Alternatively TWRP can also be used instead of ClockworkMod which is fully touch based. As far as I searched, I could not find TWRP exclusively for P275. BTW, what happens if you go into recovery mode now with stock ROM (powering up while holding home and power keys)? Do you get an option to install ROM/Zip?

Comment: Your question should have been "How do I scroll up/down on Micromax Funbook P275?"; because that's your concern, not installing Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

Flashing CWM recovery directly from your Micromax Funbook.
This method is for those who do not want to use a computer to flash cwm recovery or do not have access to a computer to do the same.

Give me credits only for the method. Not for the app and the recovery image.

Things Required:-

1. Data Connection on your Tablet. (via WIFI)
2. An file manager that supports archives. Eg ES File Explorer.
3. A Usable and working mind.

Steps:-

1. Download the necessary files from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?6wn2dow0lz9qoot).
2. Extract the file to the root of your "internal sd card" and you will get 2 file First "Novotools_v1.0" and the Second "recovery.img".
3. Install the app Novotools_v1.0.
4. Run Novotools and you will see and option Flash Recovery
5. Click it and the recovey will be flashed onto your phone.
6. Reboot in recovery with the help of the application or the old method by Holding the Home/Options and the Power button.
7. Now you have fully functional CWM recovery.

Using this custom CWM, you can scroll in the funbook recovery mode using the menu button alone.